# Options Menu dialog showing a very small width

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-optionsmenu

I have a options menu, and the item on that shows a dialog. For some reason its show up with very small width. I wonder why. Below is dialog code and the optionsuserdetails xml. I know I am missing something really silly. Sorry for the long code, but the problem could be anywhere in this options menu display.

```
case God.USER_DETAILS:
            userDetails = new Dialog(this);
            userDetails.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            userDetails.setContentView(R.layout.optionsuserdetails);
            userDetails.setCancelable(true);
            userName = (TextView) userDetails.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            userName.setText(God.appConfiguration.getString(God.nameKey, "-"));
            drivingLicense = (TextView) userDetails.findViewById(R.id.drivingLicense);
            drivingLicense.setText(God.appConfiguration.getString(God.drivingLicenseKey, "-"));
            vehicleNumber = (TextView) userDetails.findViewById(R.id.vehicleNumber);
            vehicleNumber.setText(God.appConfiguration.getString(God.vehicleRegistrationNumberKey,
                    "-"));
            phoneNumber = (TextView) userDetails.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            phoneNumber.setText(God.appConfiguration.getString(God.phoneNumberKey, "-"));
            userDetails.show();
            break;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcornersgreyback"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Personal Details"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="These are the details you have provided during registration."
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the name you provided during registration."
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Driving License Number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drivingLicense"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the driving license number you provided during registration."
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="License Plate (Vehicle)"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vehicleNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the license plate number of the vehicle you are driving."
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone Number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the phone number you provided during registration."
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit : drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#eeeeee" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#cccccc" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

[image: taxeeta home screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this after userDetails.setContentView()

```
userDetails.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: This worked, I used `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Then If userDetails is a dialog, instead of using setContentView() , why don't you use setContentView(id,layout params). If you want to decide spacing of elements in your dialog then you can use userDetails.setView(mEditText, 10, 10, 10, 10);

Comment: Thats a good idea, but I still dont know why the layout is smashing. I mean I just need enough to show the content, I dont need fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the drawable you are using i.e. roundcornersgreyback is of very small width. Try using a larger image for the same. Make sure you are placing the image in the correct drawable folder with respect to your device target and image resolution(i.e. hdpi, mdpi, ldpi etc)

Comment: I have added the drawable content. Can you help pin point where I am goofing up please. Thanks.

Comment: Even after I remove the drawable the widht does not fix. Its not that I guess. your call.